# unable to start jetty service through command in window 7

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I am using jetty-9.1.1.v20140108 and tried to start jetty service through the command line 
showing me the following error. for this, using the JRE "1.7.0_02".

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot read file: modules\npn\npn-1.7.0_02.mod
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerModule(Modules.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerAll(Modules.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

Comment: 1. Why do you use prehistoric JRE? 2. What command you are you invoking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty is looking for a .mod file corresponding to the version of the JRE you are using, but it isn't included in your distribution of Jetty.

In your Jetty/modules/npn directory, make a copy of "npn-1.7.0_04.mod" and name it "npn-1.7.0_02.mod".

Open the file in a text editor and replace all occurrences of "1.1.0.v20120525" with "1.0.0.v20120402".

See http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/npn-chapter.html#npn-versions for more information.

Answer (score 0):

We found the same problem on Windows Server 2008. It happens when Jetty is trying to read the module configuration files and is due to a fault in the check for readability.

In the jetty source file FS.java line 39 a check is made using java.nio, to see if the file is readable:

```
public static boolean canReadFile(Path path)
{
    return Files.exists(path) && Files.isRegularFile(path) && Files.isReadable(path);
}
```

The call to isReadable is slow and fails, see also:
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-discuss/2012-July/000672.html

The file itself is in fact readable and can be successfully read from Java, but the isReadable incorrectly returns false.

There are two possible workarounds:

1. Upgrade to Java 8
2. Remove the check for isReadable from the Jetty source (in any case if the file wasn't readable the reading will fail with an exception).

(See also similar question [Jetty Web Server unable to start "java.io.IOException: cannot read file:.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522962/jetty-web-server-unable-to-start-java-io-ioexception-cannot-read-file/33368687#33368687))