# Jetty Web Server unable to start "java.io.IOException: cannot read file:.."

Tags: service, jetty, embedded-jetty

```
015-04-08 12:56:30 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
java.io.IOException: Cannot read file: C:\Streem\web\modules\annotations.mod
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerModule(Modules.java:549)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Modules.registerAll(Modules.java:486)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.processCommandLine(Main.java:608)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)
```

I checked that installed Java version 1.7.0_25 and npn-1.7.0_25.mod do exist under web\modules\protonego-impl\

I am using jetty-9.2.5.v20141112 on windows 2008 R2 server

Does **annotations.mod** need something special regarding this case?

Answer (score 2):

We found the same problem on Windows Server 2008. It happens when Jetty is trying to read the module configuration files and is due to a fault in the check for readability.

In the jetty source file FS.java line 39 a check is made using java.nio, to see if the file is readable:

```
public static boolean canReadFile(Path path)
{
    return Files.exists(path) && Files.isRegularFile(path) && Files.isReadable(path);
}
```

The call to isReadable is slow and fails, see also:
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-discuss/2012-July/000672.html

The file itself is in fact readable and can be successfully read from Java, but the isReadable incorrectly returns false.

There are two possible workarounds:

1. Upgrade to Java 8
2. Remove the check for isReadable from the Jetty source (in any case if the file wasn't readable the reading will fail with an exception).

(See also similar question [unable to start jetty service through command in window 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364409/unable-to-start-jetty-service-through-command-in-window-7))

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental I/O error, something prevented Jetty from reading that file.

Try some basic troubleshooting ...

- File permissions?
- Windows File Locking issue? (a different process has that file open?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I recently discovered that this problem is only happening on windows 2008 R2 but not on the windows 2012. I will look into more why this is happening and report back.